# Are there CPUs with cache line widths others than powers of 2?

Tags: caching, cpu

Does anyone know of CPUs where the cache line widths are anything other than powers of 2?

Comment: is there any data in a computer's memory of a size other than a power of 2 ?

Comment: Probably not. Anything other than a power of two would severely complicate the hardware.

Comment: @Mystical: can you post a proper reply so I can mark it the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

This goes back to how computers store information and handle instructions in general, through binary(base 2) numbers.  This logically is the most simple that you can break anything down to either something is or it is not; 1 or 0.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking about cache line widths, not why binary is used in computers =-)

Comment: My bad went off on a tangent kinda, but I believe its basically for the same reason. Cache's are components in the datapath of a computer these components handle different sized instructions the instructions themselves are always powers of two.